# Function to add two matrices mod 2

Tags: matrix, function-construction, modular-arithmetic

I have:

```
lightstep[m_, gg_] :=
 Which[gg == {1, 1}, m = Mod[m + m, 2]]
```

Then I entered:

```
A = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

And I tried:

```
lightstep[A, {1, 1}]
```

And got this message:

Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.

Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.

Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 0.

General::stop: Further output of Set::setraw will be suppressed during this calculation.

And this output:

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

Why the message?

**Update:** Thanks for the help everyone. I was able to complete my project.

```
lightstep[m_, gg_] := Module[{
   m1 = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
   m2 = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
   m3 = {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}},
   m4 = {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
   m5 = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},
   m6 = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
   m7 = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}},
   m8 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
   m9 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
   },
  Which[
   gg == {1, 1}, Mod[m + m1, 2],
   gg == {1, 2}, Mod[m + m2, 2],
   gg == {1, 3}, Mod[m + m3, 2],
   gg == {2, 1}, Mod[m + m4, 2],
   gg == {2, 2}, Mod[m + m5, 2],
   gg == {2, 3}, Mod[m + m6, 2],
   gg == {3, 1}, Mod[m + m7, 2],
   gg == {3, 2}, Mod[m + m8, 2],
   gg == {3, 3}, Mod[m + m9, 2]
   ]]
```

Then:

```
DynamicModule[
 {m = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, gg = {0, 0}},
 Dynamic@(
   If[gg == {0, 0}, {}, m = lightstep[m, gg]; gg = {0, 0}]; 
   Pane[TableForm[
     MapIndexed[
      Button["   ", gg = #2, ImageSize -> {420/(3 + 1), 420/(3 + 1)}, 
        Background -> {Black, RGBColor[1, .81, 0]}[[1 + #1]]] &, 
      m, {2}]], {450, 450}, Alignment -> Center]
   )]
```

This was with help from (http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle/)[http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle/]

Comment: You need `HoldFirst` or friends. Take a look here: [Attempting to make an assignment to the argument of a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/5478)

Comment: `lightstep[m_, gg_] := Which[gg == {1, 1}, Return[Mod[m + m, 2]]]` will add two matrices mod 2. If you want to modify your original matrix, you could then use `A = lightstep[A, {1, 1}]`

Comment: When m is a matrix over the Galois field `{0, 1}` , `Mod[m + m, 2`]  is mathematically the zero matrix with same dimensions as m. If the 1st argument of `lightship` is such a matrix, it is better written `lightstep[m_, gg_] := Which[gg == {1, 1}, ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[m]]]`

Comment: You can not assign to a formal argument of a function within the function body. Formal arguments appearing the body are replaced by their passed value before any assignments done in the body are evaluated.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help.